# Wowza stream time measurement without spamming additional threads

Tags: java, multithreading, wowza

I'm trying to write module which will monitor how long did user watch stream. It's not live stream, but a video on demand.

My question is what is most efficient way to do so. I went this route:

created class that implements `IMediaStreamActionNotify2` and then when `onPlay` event is triggered I would create new thread that would periodically check for elapsed time since the start of the stream and update `duration` variable.

This is the way I decided to run additional thread:

```
BalanceTimerMonitor btm = new BalanceTimerMonitor(...);

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(btm, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

BalanceTimerMonitor implements `Runnable`

Now all of this works, but I'm concerned about amount of new threads created for every stream, since I assume that each stream already runs as separate thread from main wowza app. Will this big amount of threads slow down my server? Is there another more elegant way of measuring stream duration?

Comment: hi Dexa, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

My approach is that I have a single thread that loops over the connected clients and the Wowza API allows me to query the elapsed time for each connected client. I use the same trick in another project, but in that case, I don't deal with the identity of players. And you can use `IClient.getTimeRunningSeconds()` to get the time, don't need to administer it on your own. Hope it helped!

Comment: when you say elapsed time for each connected client, does it take in count paused video? Since client can be connected but with video paused, in which case it shouldn't count seconds as watched.

Comment: Need to check the API docs, not sure. But there is connection timestamp also available, so hopefully pause does not count.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I've tested mentioned method, but it just return time of duration of created stream, not time played.

Comment: I see. BTW your code uses a single thread only in the pool, so no worries.. :-)